# Continuous deployment to Azure Functions with Github

Tags: azure, .net-core, azure-functions, continuous-deployment

I'm trying to set up continuous deployment to Azure functions for a precompiled .NET core app. Source code here: https://github.com/danoleary/precompiledtest

I have connected the repo to my functions app, and when I check in the solution builds successfully. However, after that I see

```
Syncing 0 function triggers
Deployment successful.
```

What do I need to do to get Azure to recognise the function?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your app does not look like it was created by the latest tooling. I just tried creating a new v2 (Core) Function App with the latest VS 2017, and ended up with https://github.com/davidebbo-test/FunctionAppVS2017v2. Note how the csproj has:

```
<ItemGroup>
  <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Functions" Version="1.0.6" />
</ItemGroup>
```

And it works fine via continuous deployment. By contrast, yours doesn't reference `Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Functions`, and looks different in other ways.

How did you create it?

Comment: I cloned the repo from a tutorial online, so it's possible that was out of date. I'm working on a mac so don't have visual studio, but I'll have a go tonight using the repo you've shared here.

Comment: The sample application in this answer no longer appears to work. I get the same "Syncing 0 function triggers with payload size 2 bytes..." message as in the original question when deploying commit 3f1ef7

Comment: @Enrico I just tried it and it worked fine with a clean new v2 app, and git pushing this exact repo to it.